# How do I calculate based on two menu options?

Tags: python, function, menu, arguments, parameter-passing

[Instruction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEk8E.png)

There is suppose to be an image but I am not sure if you can see it?

I have to present a user with a menu to determine which style truck then with another menu for them to select rates by week or daily. Then I have to get how many days/weeks and how many miles the truck was taken. All that information has to be  calculated based on two menu selections and their input. How do I say if A and 1 then equals .... I know how to use an if statement with one variable but I do not know how to merge all these inputs to calculate effectively. 
please advise. Below is the coding I have so far.

```
def main():
    print('Please select from the following rental truck options')
    firstMenu()
    print("Please Tell us how many Days/Weeks you have rented our truck and how many miles were driven")
    milesTime()

def firstMenu():
    menu = input("Please bhoose from the following options(A, B, C, D)and press enter:\n"
                 "A = Class A Truck\n"
                 "B = Class B Truck\n"
                 "C = Class C Truck")
     if menu == str('A'):
         secondMenu()
     elif menu == str('B'):
         secondMenu()
     elif menu == str('C'):
         secondMenu()

    firstMenu()

def secondMenu():
    print('Please enter code for Daily or Weekly Rate')
    print("1 = Daily")
    print("2 = Weekly")
    option2 = input()
    secondMenu()

def milesTime():
    miles = input("Please Enter number of Miles Driven")
    time = input("Please Enter the number of days/weeks the truck was rented")
    milesTime()

def calculate():
    while firstMenu == 'A':
```

Comment: Please don't yell at me I am a noob at stackoverflow and python. I've been working on this for 4 hours with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def main():
    while True:
        menu()
        print('*' * 80)

def menu():
    class_list = ['A', 'B', 'C']
    user_class = input("Please bhoose from the following options(A, B, C, D)and press enter:\n"
                 "A = Class A Truck\n"
                 "B = Class B Truck\n"
                 "C = Class C Truck\n")
    if user_class not in class_list:
        raise ValueError('invalid classification!')
    else:
      user_class = class_list.index(user_class)
    print('Please enter code for Daily or Weekly Rate')
    print("1 = Daily")
    print("2 = Weekly")
    rent_type = input()
    if rent_type not in ['1', '2']:
        raise ValueError('invalid rental type')
    miles_time(user_class, rent_type)

def miles_time(user_class, rent_type):
    data = [
      [19.95, 0.59, 125.68],
      [29.95, 0.79, 188.68],
      [39.95, 0.85, 251.68]
    ]
    miles = int(input("Please Enter number of Miles Driven\n"))
    time = int(input("Please Enter the number of days/weeks the truck was rented\n"))
    user_data = data[user_class]
    user_rental = 0
    if rent_type == '1':
        user_rental = user_data[0] * time + miles * user_data[1]
    else:
        if miles <= time * 200:
            user_rental = user_data[2] * time
        else:
            user_rental = user_data[2] * time + (miles - 200) * user_data[1]
    print(user_rental)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Not fully tested. But two given test cases passed.

Comment: You are amazing this is exactly what I needed! If you are ever available for tutoring please let me know